# Initialization of unique_ptr as a class member variable

Tags: c++, initialization, unique-ptr

In C++, Is there a difference between using braces when initializing the unique_ptr and not using them in this code?

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass()
{
public:
  MyClass();
private:
  std::unique_ptr<TT> tt{};
}

// MyClass.cpp
MyClass() {
}
```

Do I even need to initialize the unique_ptr?

Comment: Default initialization will do the same thing, calling the default `unique_ptr` constructor, which initializes the pointer to point to `nullptr`. In this instance, they are equivalent.

Comment: In this case no difference. Just don't use the round brackets, `std::unique_ptr<TT> tt();`, or you get a declaration for a `tt` function that returns a `unique_ptr`

Comment: the reason why I ask, is because clang-tidy complains that I am not initializing the pointer in the constructor if I remove the brackets, but I don't see any harm in not doing it explicitly

Comment: @AndresLa There is no pointer in  your class.  There's a `std::unique_ptr`, which is a class in its own right, and that has a default constructor which will be called if you don't explicitly initialise `tt`.  So clang-tidy should not be complaining here, but if adding the braces shuts it up then so be it.

Comment: There is no harm. I like clean diagnostic output, so I'd get rid of the nag-message with the least intrusive method you have available, and that's probably the curly braces.